# Downloading .zip file and storing in a folder using Python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, zip

DISCLAIMER: It is my humble request to not flag this question as a duplicate, I do understand there are several other similar questions already answered on SO, but they do not work for my particular case and I wish to find out why.

I have a private URL  which when you search in a browser, prompts the user to save a .zip file (It shows that window, Open the file or save file).

Currently using  Python requests to go to the URL and download the .zip in my desired location.

I do not wish to extract the .zip file. I just want it saved in a particular location.

I have searched for this quite extensively but none of the answers on SO seem to solve my problem.

This is my code so far. Now the GET request does happen and a .zip file does get stored. But for some reason, it is much larger than it should be (I mean by an extra 100KB). I do not understand this. I feel it has something to do with chunk size.

```
r = requests.get(URL, verify=False, cookies= coks)
with open(saved_path, 'wb') as fd:
 for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=256):
            fd.write(chunk)
```

> fd.write(r.content)

> fd.write(r.text)

also don't work.
There are suggestions in a few other answers to use urllib, but I am not aware of how to specify multiple cookie values and SSL verify = false in it.
I would prefer a solution in Requests. But if not possible in Requests, please help me with a solution with urllib

Please assist, thanks in advance.

Comment: The original .zip file is only 2KB or 3KB.

Comment: I think that `r.iter_content(chunk_size=256)` is unnecessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple and working solution:

```
import requests

URL = "https://some.url/output.zip"

r = requests.get(URL)
with open("output.zip", "wb") as fd:
    fd.write(r.content)
```

Also cleaner version (using `pathlib`):

```
import requests
import pathlib

URL = "https://some.url/output.zip"

downloaded_file = pathlib.Path.cwd() / "output.zip"

downloaded_file.write_bytes(requests.get(URL).content)
```

Comment: Thanks, this definitely helps

Comment: for some zip files, this method only downloads an empty 1kb zip.